# C++ expression and activity cin.getline

Tags: c++

I need to get an output of the input that I have created the first one, but I maybe do something wrong because the second output won't print out the input

```
cout << "Movie Name: " << endl;
cin.getline(movie_name, SIZE);
cin.ignore();

cout << "Movie Name: " << movie_name << endl;
```

The last line only output "Movie Name:" but won't print out the input that I have created.

Comment: are you using `cin >> something` before `cout << "Movie Name: " << endl;`?  If so then see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed, my bad.

Comment: _"I need to get an output of the input that I have created the first one, but I maybe do something wrong because the second output won't print out the input"_ This is art.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cout<< "Movie Name: " << endl;
cin >> movie_name >> endl;
cout << "Movie Name: " << movie_name << endl;
```